# Pandas remove certain headers from the dataframe while exporting

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a table which is similar as shown below :

| OpenTable |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| A | B | C |
| Four | Five | Six |
| D | E | F |

When I read it in pandas with `df = pd.read_excel('myfilename.xlsx')` function. I used pandas to remove the Nan values from a particular column.
It adds headers names to the empty headers like below:

| OpenTable | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| A | B | C |
| Four | Five | Six |
| D | E | F |

When I export this file using `df.to_excel('my filename.xlsx')`
It still retains the headers as below, Is there any way to ignore those and write to excel?

Comment: You could just give it a list of empty column names like `df.columns = ['OpenTable','','']` before you export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.to_excel('my fillename.xlsx', header=['OpenTable', '', ''])
```